# pyspark mongoDB connector issue

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark

I am on spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7, Scala 2.11.8 & python3.5.

For spark-mongo connector i am using "mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar" from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.0.0/

Now after placing that jar in ../spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars path, I am starting my ./pyspark as following official mongo doc site https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/#tutorials

```
./bin/pyspark --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection?readPreference=primaryPreferred" 
          --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection" \
          --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0
```

Everything is fine, i get my sparksession object as spark.

Now when I am trying to load a collection into a dataframe

```
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection").load()
```

I am getitng this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$$anonfun$4.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$$anonfun$4.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.connectionString(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.connectionString(ReadConfig.scala:39)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:51)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:39)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:124)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:39)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$class.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:113)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$.apply(ReadConfig.scala:39)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:67)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.ConnectionString
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
```

I just can't figure out: What I am doing wrong and what i am missing

-do i have to add any dependent jar

-or this connector is only for  2.0.x   and not on spark2.1.0  (never tried on spark2.0.x)

- and what if there is a authorization on mongoDB , then how will be my uri look like

-As it show connectionString but i have rechecked like 100 times(same works in pymongo connection url).

-Also tried the same with session builder object but No result

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Please help me sort this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It works with Spark 2.1.x, tough you need to include MongoDB Java driver in classpath, along with the connector. Edit `spark-defaults.conf`, such that, it includes the necessary jar files:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /opt/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar,/opt/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /opt/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar,/opt/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath /opt/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar,/opt/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /opt/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar,/opt/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It appears that the mongo-spark-connector only works in Python 2.x. Once I changed to 2.7 from 3.5, the mongodb data loaded with no issues.